# Any way to stream Live TV from one PC to another in Windows Media Center?

Tags: streaming, tv

I have one computer (my TV Server) that has a multi-tuner CableCARD in it, so I can watch/record Live TV in Windows Media Center.  The problem is, I can only watch that on one TV.  Is there any way I can set it up to where my TV Server will stream the Live TV to another PC that is hooked up to a TV in a different room??  I don't want to use an Xbox 360 as an extender, I want access to programs like Spotify, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop the CableCARD in something like [this](http://www.silicondust.com/products/models/hdhr3-cc/) and stream content to any PC.  Looks like there is a "[Play To](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/play-to)" feature in Windows Media Center that will do the job, too.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I'm gonna buy the HDHomeRun Prime.  Can't believe I haven't seen that before...